# Unzip a file in Background C#

Tags: c#, zip, background-process

I am using this code in C# to unZip a file.

```
  ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Path.Combine(Dir.FullName, "Preview.zip"), Dir.FullName);
```

It takes quite some time to unzip the file. Is there a way to do that in the background as soon as the programm starts?

Comment: *"in the background"* of what? What UI technology the programm is using? Are you aware about existence of multithreading: threads, tasks, timers, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1). This will run the supplied action on a background thread, and return a task that completes when the work is finished. Use [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) to handle the result or exception of the work and do whatever you want to do when the work has finished.